# How to scrape a new link with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I started using Scrapy recently, so I`m not that skilled with it, so this is really a newbie question.

I am scraping some random convention for practice, I have scraped the names and booth numbers, but I also want links from the companies, that are inside a new window, I`ve found and stored the link from anchor tags, but I do not know how to scrape those new links, any kind of help or direction will be lovely

```
import scrapy

class ConventionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'convention'
    allowed_domains = ['events.jspargo.com/ASCB18/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?sortMenu=102003']
    start_urls = ['https://events.jspargo.com/ASCB18/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?sortMenu=102003']

    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//*[@class="companyName"]')
        number = response.xpath('//*[@class="boothLabel"]')
        link = response.xpath('//*[@class="companyName"]')
        for row, row1, row2 in zip(name, number, link):
            company = row.xpath('.//*[@class="exhibitorName"]/text()').extract_first()
            booth_num = row1.xpath('.//*[@class="boothLabel aa-mapIt"]/text()').extract_first()
            url = row2.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()

            yield {'Company': company,'Booth Number': booth_num}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this for reference https://github.com/NilanshBansal/Craigslist_Scrapy/blob/master/craigslist/spiders/jobs.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class ConventionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'convention'
# allowed_domains = ['events.jspargo.com/ASCB18/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?sortMenu=102003']
start_urls = ['https://events.jspargo.com/ASCB18/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?sortMenu=102003']

def parse(self, response):
    name = response.xpath('//*[@class="companyName"]')
    number = response.xpath('//*[@class="boothLabel"]')
    link = response.xpath('//*[@class="companyName"]')
    for row, row1, row2 in zip(name, number, link):
        company = row.xpath('.//*[@class="exhibitorName"]/text()').extract_first()
        booth_num = row1.xpath('.//*[@class="boothLabel aa-mapIt"]/text()').extract_first()
        url = row2.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()

        yield Request(url,callback=self.parse_page,meta={'Url':url,'Company': company,'Booth_Number': booth_num)

def parse_page(self,response):
    company = response.meta.get('Company')
    booth_num = response.meta.get('Booth Number')
    website = response.xpath('//a[@class="aa-BoothContactUrl"]/text()').extract_first()

    yield {'Company': company,'Booth Number': booth_num, 'Website': website}
```

Edit: 
**Comment the line allowed_domains to let the crawler work on other domains as well.**

In reply to your code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52792350

Comment: This wouldn`t run because of SyntaxError, you forgot to add scrapy. : yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_page,meta={'Url':url,'Company': company,'Booth_Number': booth_num)

Comment: Sir, please see the import statement above: 
**from scrapy import Request**
when the import statement is added then **Request** refers to **scrapy.Request** since it is imported from the scrapy module

Comment: @Stefan in your answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/52792350/8284987 ) please change the name of the second method to **parse_page** as the callback from the parse method will go to method parse_page. Also, comment the line allowed_domains and it will work.

Comment: @nulansh bansal Of course I totally forgot about that, thanks I got it to work. It has pullled the websites, but not i the correct order, any ideas how to fix that ?

Comment: @Stefan scrapy uses asynchronous requests and that's what makes it process faster, it was originally not developed to make requests in order but now you can specify a priority attribute within the request, the higher priority request would process first. Refer: **https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects**

Comment: @Stefan if I was able to resolve your queries please accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way of doing this would be to subclass the `scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider` class instead and specify the `rule` attribute

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ConventionSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'convention'
    allowed_domains = ['events.jspargo.com/ASCB18/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?sortMenu=102003']
    start_urls = ['https://events.jspargo.com/ASCB18/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?sortMenu=102003']

    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('', ), # allow all links that match a given regex
        deny=('')), # deny all links that match given regex
        callback='parse_item', # function that gets called for each extracted link
        follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//*[@class="companyName"]')
        number = response.xpath('//*[@class="boothLabel"]')
        link = response.xpath('//*[@class="companyName"]')
        for row, row1, row2 in zip(name, number, link):
            company = row.xpath('.//*[@class="exhibitorName"]/text()').extract_first()
            booth_num = row1.xpath('.//*[@class="boothLabel aa-mapIt"]/text()').extract_first()
            # url = row2.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
            # No need to parse links because we are using CrawlSpider

            yield {'Company': company,'Booth Number': booth_num}
```

Make sure you don't use `parse` as a callback though, since `scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider` uses the `parse` method to implement its logic.

Answer (score 0):

There's an indention problem of the class function `parse_page` in your code and you name it "parse" rather than "parse_page" by mistake. That may be the reason of why your code doesn't work properly. The code modified is shown below and that works pretty well for me:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class ConventionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Convention'
    allowed_domains = ['events.jspargo.com/ASCB18/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?sortMenu=102003']
    start_urls = ['https://events.jspargo.com/ASCB18/Public/Exhibitors.aspx?sortMenu=102003']

    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//*[@class="companyName"]')
        number = response.xpath('//*[@class="boothLabel"]')
        link = response.xpath('//*[@class="companyName"]')
        for row, row1, row2 in zip(name, number, link):
            company = row.xpath('.//*[@class="exhibitorName"]/text()').extract_first(),
            booth_num = row1.xpath('.//*[@class="boothLabel aa-mapIt"]/text()').extract_first()

            next_page_url = row2.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse_page, meta={'Company': company, 'Booth Number': booth_num}, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        company = response.meta.get('Company')
        booth_num = response.meta.get('Booth Number')
        website = response.xpath('//a[@class="aa-BoothContactUrl"]/text()').extract_first()
        yield {'Company': company, 'Booth Number': booth_num, 'Website': website}
```